# Help to set up nginx+fastcgi webserver for django

Tags: django, installation, nginx, fastcgi

It is the first time that I am going to deploy a django project in a production server. I am a big fan of pure nginx+fastcgi and try to avoid apache at any cost. On the other hand I know that configuring nginx+fastcgi sometimes can be VERY painful. I wasted literally days to figure out how to set up and fix 502, 504 errors on my nginx+php-fastcgi arrangement. But if you could climb that mountain of difficulties it is rock solid and fantastic, specially for server tight resources.

So if you think this practice worth doing with django, I appreciate if you could point me to a painless tutorial to set up nginx+fastcgi to serve django, or share your experience about it

Answer (score 0):

Instead of going through all that, I suggest you look at Gunicorn, which is preconfigured to handle Django, and written in pure Python. Don't let that fool you though, it's fast. You simply proxy_pass the request to gunicorn on a unix socket or regular network port and it handles the rest. [Here's the gunicorn webpage.](http://gunicorn.org/)

Comment: Interesting! Never heard of Gunicorn. Thanks shintoist, I am going to have a look.